# julia chunk not runnable in quarto

Tags: r, julia, rstudio, quarto

I am trying to run R and Julia in the same quarto document. In RStudio, I see that the julia chunk is not runable (no 'play' button):

[image]

````
---
title: "Untitled"
format: html
---

```{r}
1+1
```

```{julia}
using DataFrames
```
````

I have `JuliaCall` package installed and julia 1.9.2 is in my system path (REPL runs outside RStudio). My R version is 4.3.1 and quarto version is 1.3.450. I am on Windows 10.

When I try to render quarto, the server keeps running but the document never renders. It seems to be stuck at chunk 2 that contains julia code. I understand that it is calling `JuliaCall` behind the scenes. But I don't see any result.

```
processing file: test.qmd
1/5                  
2/5 [unnamed-chunk-1]
3/5                  
4/5 [unnamed-chunk-2]
Julia version 1.9.2 at location C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Programs\JULIA-~1.2\bin will be used.
Loading setup script for JuliaCall...
```

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: @bretauv I've provided a reprex of a qmd file.

Comment: this works for me using VSCode, but running the second code chunk using RStudio makes the R session encounter a fatal error and abort

Comment: @Mark, thanks for checking. I tried but get the same issue in VSCode.

Comment: hmm interesting! Does it still use JuliaCall at that point? Because for me, that launches a Julia instance in the terminal, not using JuliaCall

Comment: @Mark If you render the doc then, yes, it uses JuliaCall. Otherwise, as you said, it launches julia in the terminal. I found that the main culprit is JuliaCall as per this github issue: https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/205

Comment: if you have your answer, write an answer and mark it solved! :-)

Comment: The issue I mentioned above was not resolved for Windows. So, I opened a new issue here: https://github.com/Non-Contradiction/JuliaCall/issues/206